# What is the magnitude of variation of Earth's orbital inclination?

Tags: orbital-migration, inclination

Please excuse if this has been asked and I just didn't find it.

I have found several references that indicate that the inclination of Earth's orbit varies over a period of ~70,000 years, but I can't seem to find anything that tells what the range of variation is. I know that it's currently at 1.57° to the invariable plane, but I'm looking for the value of the maximum tilt.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a [solar system model](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/375560/fulltext/55714.fg10.html) by [Varadi Runnegar and Ghil](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/375560/fulltext/55714.text.html) Earth's inclination varies between 0 and about 0.05 radians (or about 3 degrees)

The variation is rather chaotic, but you may note that there seems to have been a qualitative change in the pattern about 60-70 million years ago