# What's the angle between the sun's galactic speed and the ecliptic?

Tags: orbit, galaxy, galactic-dynamics

I know the sun wobbles up and down the galactic plane around 35myr. I don't mind about that component.
I'd like the know the angle between the linear speed of sun around the Milky Way (just the angular speed by distance to center) and the ecliptic.

I understand that the ecliptic is like a gyroscope and the angle between the ecliptic and the galactic plane is constant at 63°.
So the angle between the sun's linear speed and the ecliptic must change with time.
My second question is:
Is it correct to say that the rate of change of this angle is 360°/250myr?

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44388/16685

Comment: Thanks. That confirms that the second part of the question is right.