# Why does the axis tilt (obliquity) of Earth change over time?

Tags: solar-system, orbital-mechanics, earths-orbit

I have recently learned that the polar axis of Earth moves in a complex fashion. There are both precession and nutation. I have learned that Earth's obliquity varies between 22.1 and 24.5 degrees on a 41,000-year cycle. My questions are:

- What accounts for the change of obliquity in the range of 22.1 to 24.5 degrees besides nutation, which I assume is a relatively high-frequency process consisted of many terms (like a Fourier expansion series)?
- Do the ecliptic or the invariant plane of the solar system rotate with respect to the distant stars, and if so, are they responsible for the variation of Earth's obliquity?
- Lastly, how should we understand the period of 41,000 years. The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt) says something I found confusing.

> This cycle is a combination of precession and the largest term in the
> motion of the ecliptic

Comment: You can check EarthScience.SE

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Should I close this question?

Comment: This question is perfectly on-topic here. @NilayGhosh I don't think it's appropriate to make new members double-post - a thing which is definitely not wanted.

Comment: @planetmaker I am not saying OP to double post. I am suggesting OP that we have a sister site for Earth related topics. OP may check if there is any post on this topic.

Comment: @NilayGhosh This question is mainly about the astronomical motions of the Earth, so it's probably mostly suited to this site. Of course, EarthScience.SE should have good info regarding the irregularities of Earth's rotation, but that's on-topic here too, because it impacts every astronomical observation made from Earth's surface.

Comment: However, there are multiple questions here, and although they're related, it might be a good idea to split them up and ask about the wobbles in Earth's axial rotation and in the ecliptic plane  in separate questions.

Comment: I have some info about the stability of the ecliptic and the invariable plane here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/44412/16685 "the inclination of the ecliptic plane to the invariable plane of the Solar System varies by ~3°, over a very long time scale. The invariable plane itself is very stable relative to the International Celestial Reference Frame (ICRF)".

Comment: @PM2Ring for the link. That was useful. I have removed the duplicated post in EarthScience SE.